# By realm framework how to sync (update & download) with webserver in swift?

Tags: swift, synchronization, realm, realm-object-server

I want to take value from **local realm database** and save it to **realm object-server database** and then (after user login) I want to fetch data value from **realm object-server database**. How can I do this? Can I achieve my sync (between realm Local database and realm object-server) feature by **only Realm** without additional **web API**?

**Additionally:**

```
try! self.realm.write
  {
    self.realm.add(task)
  }
```

I observed, the above code **add** the **task** object to local database. But not **add** this **task** object to web object server database? So, my key question is How can save this task object to **remote web object server** " by Realm?

Answer (score 1):

If you open your `self.realm` as a synced Realm, the local copy of the Realm and the copy of the Realm on the server will automatically stay in sync with each other. You don't need to write any additional calls to web APIs.

To configure a Realm to sync to a server, you need to set the `syncConfiguration` property on its configuration object. Please refer to our [documentation on synced Realms](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#sync) for more information about how to use this feature.